# Pandas resample without dropping nan values

Tags: python, pandas

I have a daily measured dataset with datetime index. I am trying to resample it to monthly by only taking the data of the first available day of month.

dataframe df:

```
2010-10-04 Nan 4
2010-10-05 3   5
2010-10-06 5   2
```

I tried using

```
df.resample("MS").first()
```

But that ends up giving me

```
2010-10-01 3   4
```

instead of

```
2010-10-04 Nan   4
```

Can I avoid droping Nan values? I couldnt find a suitable parameter in the documentation.

Comment: Why do you need the resample ? Could you elaborate?

Comment: Can you please give a [mcve]? I _think_ I understand what you're asking, but I'm not sure.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

IIUC, you need the first row for each month in your dataset. I tried elaborating on your example by adding more months and from different years.

Try grouping by the `month` and take the `head(1)` for each month, assuming the data is sorted by dates.

```
#               A    B
# 2010-10-04  NaN  4.0  <----
# 2010-10-05  3.0  5.0
# 2010-10-06  5.0  2.0
# 2010-09-05  NaN  NaN  <----
# 2010-09-05  3.0  5.0
# 2010-09-06  5.0  2.0
# 2019-10-04  7.0  7.0  <----
# 2019-10-05  3.0  5.0
# 2019-10-06  5.0  2.0

df.groupby(pd.Grouper(freq="M")).head(1)
```

```
              A    B
2010-09-05  NaN  NaN
2010-10-04  NaN  4.0
2019-10-04  7.0  7.0
```

Comment: I think that's not the desired output

Comment: let me delete and check it.

Comment: Fixed. thanks for the heads up.

Comment: I was confused between resample and groupby and could not get the result I wanted. But this worked.